# Can I put a profile name in the Serverless .yml file?

Tags: serverless

I have multiple profiles in my c:\Users\myuser.aws\credentials file (for example, my personal account, and two client accounts).

I understand that I can deploy using "serverless" as follows:

```
sls deploy --aws-profile DESIRED_PROFILE_NAME
```

My question is whether I can put that "DESIRED_PROFILE_NAME" in my .yml (YAML) file, so that I could just deploy like this:

```
sls deploy
```

I'm using Python 3.9, but I don't think it matters much to the question.

Comment: There's `profile` entry in the root provider configuration, does it work for you? [Docs](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/serverless.yml#provider)

Comment: Yes, thanks.  I believe that is what I was looking for.